# error TS2339: Property '_componentTag' does not exist

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-component

I wrote an unit test with Vue, Typescript and Jest. I would like to get `_componentTag`, but I got the following error. How can I fix this issue?

Error:

```
error TS2339: Property '_componentTag' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>'.

    21       const noSsr = wrapper.vm.$children[0].$options._componentTag;
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_componentTag` is internal property and not a part of public API.

It can be accessed by disabling type checking:

```
wrapper.vm.$children[0].$options['_componentTag'];
```